# Steps to convert iPad app to universal, ideally with just one storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I've had several attempts to try and convert my iPad app to make it universal.

I'm only supporting landscape on iPhone / iPad.

My existing iPad setup uses a storyboard without autolayout, which works fine.

My app had lots of images and about 10 screen each with a minimum of 6 views on each, however some have 20 or 30.

I decided a couple of weeks ago that it would a far greater nightmare with all the images, so I've created paint code classes for all my images.

When I first turned on sizing classes / autolayout, Xcode asked if it should enable suggested layouts, this seemed to make sense. However it's made a real mess of the any / any layout.

Without adjusting the sizing classes setting any / any, I tried to install constraints for differing sizing classes. I want to make views bigger to fill the space, so I installed constraints with equal width (with aspect ratio) to subview with a multiplier so I would get proportional sized views. However this means I have about three sets of constraints per view. Which is a nightmare on my simple screen.

I then thought it might be better in my case to leave my iPad storyboard and have an iPhone storyboard. But my  iPhone 6+ layout won't look very good. Turning on sizing classes made little sense with multiple storyboards.

I'm now thinking I could click the sizing class to regular / regular and compact / compact and have different views for each?

However any / any, which I can't get any sort of layout to look good, will still need views?

I'm also wondering if should let Xcode setup autolayout when I first enable it? As I say any / any looks bad.

I was thinking I could just plop my views in a vague position with any / any, apply suggested constraints, then click / flip to compact / compact and regular / regular and move things around.

I guess I'd also need to do that for compact / regular for 6+ too.

I'm just not sure what steps to take, I can't even think of workable plan b.

I've watched a million videos and feel I understand but I can't put it into practice.

HELP

Comment: Unfortunately your question is probably too broad to answer, especially without specific information on the problems you are trying to solve. Personally I try and layout as much as possible using any,any and on,y use size classes where there are specific requirements. Trying to convert a complex non-auto layout storyboard to auto layout is going to take a. It of work, I doubt there is a quick fix. One thing to keep experiment with is the multiplier rather than the constant in constraints. Often IB steers you to using  constants but  multiplier lets you e.g. make a view 33% of the screen width

Comment: Auto layout takes practice; try to fix the main element(s) in the scene and then relate the other elements to that or them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Suggest steps would be:

- When we use autolayout and size classes, We always take start from wAny hAny
- Take your simple Screen First Let say your login screen on ipad LandScape without autolayout will look like this:

[image]

Now you enable autolayout and size classes. Change Scene size to inferred (600, 600).

[image]

Now your view look terrible:

[image]

First Adjust it by just moving the views to center and correct places like this.

[image]

Now we are all set for applying autolayout constraints.

First give constraints to parentview(grey view). Unless parent view has correct constraints, childs view cannot be given correct constraints. So always make sure parent view have correct constraints.

Now we select the grey view and apply constriants like this:

- Center vertically and horizontally in container.

[image]

- Add width and Height Constraints. You got options. Give fixed width and height and modify it for different classes. like this:

[image]

Or you can add proportional constraints for width or height.(Better)

Now start with childs. Give them leading, trailing, top and height.

Height of label is 50 for wR hAny and 40 for wR hCompact

Final Results:

IPAD LANDSCAPE:
[image]

IPHONE LANDSCAPE:

[image]

Autolayout and size class are great and easy when someone get used to it.

HOPE IT HELP.

Comment: Thanks @irfan you mention setting constraints to the super view, I didn't think it needed them? Also when you add proportional constraints would you click and change from any / any to another sizing class, or would you add them within any / any ?

Comment: By superview I mean In this example the grey view that has label. In every screen there is a hierarchy of views. We start from parent view and then subviews. Well proportional constraint are added in any / any. These constraints are same for all size class(width or height change according to proportion) except you can add constant in specific class.

Comment: For example (any / any = ) view1.width = .5 * view2.width
And : in other class you can do this: view1.width = .5*view2.width + someConstant

Comment: Ahh OK thanks, would you agree with the @Usama that any / any should be for iPad?

Comment: Having said that, with using multipliers on any / any, I doubt this will look good on ipad.

Comment: any / any means for all layout. (All layout include iphone* and ipads). So a label that you set in any / any and you want to have increase width on ipad. You have to change from any / any to wR/ hAny

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94072/discussion-between-irfan-and-jules).

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options

1) Create separate layout for iPhone and iPad. In this options you might have to compromise targeted customization for iPhone6+. This option will consume less time, and if you have a time constraint or you think that you are not convenient working with autolayouts then go with this option.

2) Using any/any size class and add constraints to make you interface alright for iPad. After that only modify/add those constraints for iPhone specific size classes which needs to be adjusted. Once you have layout set with any/any for one of the device either iPhone or iPad, you will be surprised to know how much less constraints you will have to modify for specific size classes. This option requires good understanding of autolayouts or even if you are not convenient working with autolayout but willing to try and have no problem with time constraint then you should definitely go with this option.

Comment: Thanks @Usama when you add specific sizing class constraints would you click and change from any / any to another sizing class, or would you add them within any / any ?

Comment: suppose there is constraint which is for any/any but you want that to be applied for only regular/regular and modify the multiplier of same constraint for compact/regular. you will have to uninstall for any/any and install the constraint for regular/regular and then move to compact/regular in interface builder and create the constraint again. If you only need different constant for specific size class you can use the same constraint and specify different constant for specific size class but if you need different multiplier then you have to add separate constraints for both size classes

Comment: Would you work on one control at a time making it look good across sizing classes or do everything in any / any first then look at other sizing classes.

Comment: everything in any/any size class first